# symfony2: validation depending on query

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

After updating an object using a form, for a certain value in one of the fields (`foo`), I would like to check if there are persisted children objects with a specific property value.

So I have created a custom validator passing doctrine as argument, but.. how to pass the object (or the id of the object) and the certain value of `foo` to create the query?

This is my code:

```
class ChildCategoryHasItsOwnPageValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    protected $doctrine;

    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }


    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
      //...
    }
}
```

---

```
Placas\FrontendBundle\Entity\Category:
    properties:
        ownPage:
            - Placas\FrontendBundle\Validator\Constraints\ChildCategoryHasItsOwnPage: ~
```

---

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ChildCategoryHasItsOwnPage extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'This category has a child category with an own page. You can not define an own page for this category.';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
      return "child_category_has_its_own_page";
    }
}
```

---

```
Placas\FrontendBundle\Entity\Category:
    properties:
        ownPage:
            - Placas\FrontendBundle\Validator\Constraints\ChildCategoryHasItsOwnPage: ~
```

Comment: Please write code in English.

Comment: Get inspiration by reading code of UniqueEntity and UniqueEntityValidator (it does some checks in DB)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will help you: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

It should work like this for you:
(Symfony 2.4 version)

Your config:

```
Placas\FrontendBundle\Entity\Category:
    constraints:
        - Callback: [validate]
```

In you entity:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextInterface;

class Category
{
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        $children = $this->getChildren(); // assuming you have this relationship and its getter
        foreach ($children as $child)
        {
            if ($child->foo != '') // or whatever test you want to make
            {
                $context->addViolationAt(
                   'foo',
                   'This category has a child category with an own page. You can not define an own page for this category.',
                   array(),
                   null
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```